# Error while setting YTPlayer property youtube player api ios

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I'm trying to embed a video in an app, using a button to start and a button to stop the video.
I'm following the [official google developer guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#add-a-ytplayerview-via-interface-builder-or-the-storyboard) to achieve this, but when it says to enter in the ViewController.h class the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;
```

it displays this [error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7esq.png)

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dragged your `IBOutlet` in the wrong place.  Put it in an `@interface`.